# What server information is possible to obtain only using FTP?

Tags: ftp, shared-hosting

What server information is possible to obtain only using FTP and how would you obtain it?

This is a shared hosting situation and I would like to at least get information about Apache.

Answer (score 1):

For apache information you can run

```
$ lynx --head http://www.example.com
```

If you want to do this from a browser read [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976442/how-do-i-send-a-head-request-manually-using-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get any information about apache using FTP only. This is especially true if your user is chrooted. In this case, you will not be able to access any configuration or log file.

It is easier to get such information by trying to access a forbidden or not-found page. The default page will return some useful information. You can also try telnet to the port 80.